# Convert 15 digit number string to java8 timestamp

Tags: datetime, java-8, type-conversion, date-formatting

I am struggling to convert a big 15 digit number string to a date format.

Sample code :

```
String dateInString = "201410051252323";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInString, formatter);
```

I am getting following exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2014100591523' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Can anyone please suggest the best way to do this in Java 8

Answer (score 1):

You have the right the idea, but there are two issues with your code--one syntactic, and the other logistic:

- Your pattern expects the string to be formatted with hyphens and colons and spaces. For example, "yyyy-MM-dd" will match "2014-10-05", but not "20141005". To match the latter, just drop the hyphens and use "yyyyMMdd".
- You use a 'Z' in your pattern for the final digit, indicating that you expect a time zone offset in your string. But the 'Z' pattern matches offsets like "+0000" and "-8000", not a single digit. Also, to represent datetimes with a time zone, you should use the `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` class instead of `LocalDateTime`

I'm not sure which time zone the '3' in your example string is supposed to represent, if it is indeed supposed to represent a zone offset at all. If you do not have control over the formatting of your data set, you'll have to peel off the final digit and handle it separately.

```
    String dateInString = "201410051252323";
    String dateTimeString = dateInString.substring(0, 14); // "20141005125232"
    String zoneDigitString = dateInString.substring(14); // "3"
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"); // no "Z" 
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);

    /* Manually convert zoneDigitString to a ZoneId here */
    ZoneId zone = ...; 

    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = dateTime.atZone(zone);
```

You'll have to handle the "..." part on your own, depending on what "3" represents.

Comment: Thanks for that. Really helpful :)